# help with Harmonic Sequence inequality proof by using induction of H2^n <= n+1

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I tried to prove Harmonic sequence inequality by using induction. I couldn't solve it.I'll glad for some enlightenments or any help.
Let:
$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n} = H_n$$
Prove:
$$H_{2^n} <= 1+n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$H_{2^n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots +\frac{1}{2^n-1}+\frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$H_{2^n}\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n}$$

that is for each $2^{j}\leq k<2^{j-1}$ bound $\frac{1}{k}\leq\frac{1}{2^j}$
$$H_{2^n}\leq 1+2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+4\cdot\frac{1}{4}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\ldots+2^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^n}=n+\frac{1}{2^n}$$